# Sql fetch result from multiple table having same column but no relation

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello all how can get two same name column from two different table as single result in two different column as combine result.

Eg: customer table have column customerid

| custmerId | customerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 2 | row |

Order Table

it has also column customerid

| custmerId | orderName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | order1 |
| 4 | order2 |
| 5 | order3 |

Expected Output

| custmerId | custmerId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
|  | 5 |

**Note**: There is no relation between both table

Comment: Add proper schema with dummy data

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data.

Comment: Use alias for same column names so that you don't get ambiguity error.

Comment: @Shibon added dummy data

Comment: @Akina added exact details

Comment: ?? Where `custmerId=2` from `customer` table is disappeared?

Comment: "There is no relation between both table" - what does that mean? If there is no relation. how could the rows be identified?

Comment: @Akina updated table yeah 2 was missing

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible. it's better to use aliases or group by.

you can use alias, a ['SELECT AS'](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_as.asp), to seprate column names:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID as OCustomerID, c.CustomerId as CCustomerID
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o;
```

Comment: Stop guessing what the author wants and proposing strange queries. Let him/her clarify what is really wanted.

Comment: Added exact requirement please help

Comment: which column is for Customers table? 
@Coder

Answer (score 0):

If by result, you mean a simple SELECT query result, you can just indicate the column name in a SELECT clause and separate the table names with a comma in the FROM clause. see example below:

`SELECT customerID FROM Customers, Orders;`

You can also add a "WHERE" clause at the end if you have conditions the query needs to meet.

Comment: Your query is invalid and will not be executed. Never use columns without alias that might be ambiguous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support FULL JOIN, so

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT customerId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY custmerId) rn
          FROM customer ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT customerId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY custmerId) rn
          FROM order ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT rn FROM cte1 UNION SELECT rn FROM cte2 )
SELECT cte1.customerId, cte2.customerId
FROM cte3
LEFT JOIN cte1 USING (rn)
LEFT JOIN cte2 USING (rn);
```

Remember that an outer client software which accesses the output rowset columns by the name (not by the posession) won't print the result correctly. In this case you must assign unique aliases to the output columns. For example,

`.. SELECT cte1.customerId AS customer_id, cte2.customerId AS order_id ..`